# How to move a div in the bottom of the windows screen

Tags: html, css

I need to put a div "propped" to the bottom of the windows browsers.
Like the one with `chat` on facebook. It must be positioned always at the `bottom` of the screen, also when I scroll the page.

Fixed? I know IE7 sucks on it...

How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#yourdiv {
    position: fixed; /* This will be always visible and positioned where you want */
    bottom: 0; /* place it to the bottom */
    z-index: 9999; /* You may want to be sure no other elements will be displayed on top of it, raise this if it's still being displayed under other elements */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zQNcu/9/

Position:fixed is the way to go. This is the only way to have a div being displayed at the same position regardless of page scrolling. Otherwise, if this doesn't work (older browsers perhaps), you need JS to keep it at a specific position regardless of page scroll.

Comment: it doesnt take the width of the whole screen... :(

Comment: add position:relative; to its parent element, and width:100%; to it

Comment: Uhm...seems to also works putting width 100% to the fixed div. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Ah ok you say the same thing :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use the `position: fixed;` css property

```
#somediv {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
*html #somediv {
    position: absolute;
}
```